# Can someone please explain why I would need to reference two models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Can someone explain how I would reference another model in Django and also why I would need to?

```
class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my first class and I need to reference it in the class BannerPost below.

```
class BannerPost(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

Comment: What do you mean by reference?

Comment: I need to add bannerpost as a reference to post, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You can add a attribute with foreignkey reference!

Comment: Can you explain what that does please. I have seen that a few times but wasn't 100% whether it was the right thing.

Comment: Just ask what you actually wants !!!

Comment: @MaxLoyd 
“This is called relationships in db tables. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”
Also you can check this "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#relationships" to know more about implementation in django.

Comment: @bak2trak Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaxLoyd It's still under `unanswered` category hence added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about foreign_keys here,so you need to add a foreign key field in you BannerPost model:

```
post = models.ForeignKey(post)
```

“This is called relationships in db tables. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.” Also you can check this "docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#relationships" to know more about implementation in django.